# Android: Can't install my own apk on tablet but working in eclipse (installing through eclipse also possible)

Tags: android, installation, apk

I've created my own app. It's running in the emulator, I can export it as unsigned apk and it's also running on my tablet if I start/install it through eclipse.

But if I put the apk on the tablet and try to install it without eclipse I got a notification (app not installed). 
I've looked into LogCat ( http://pastebin.com/fsSCzr5t ). I guess the problem is in line 151.
I refactored the main.xml but nothing changed.

Any hints?

thx B770

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=830 (comment 26).
Or maybe you are using JDK 7 instead of 6? Please mind that you have to develop android apps with JDK 6 only.

Comment: I use a version 6 of Java. Why does an unsigned apk need a certificate :(

Comment: I don't know why, but the apk isn't installable if I export it via Android Tools. It's installable if I copy the apk from the bin folder.

Answer (score 1):

Same happen to me. Only can install APK from bin folder. Maybe android tool is using jre7 instead of 6... I have jre and jdk 6 x86 and x64, and jre7x86 and im not sure what jre is using the android tool. Will try uninstall jre7 and come back here.

Nope.. jre7 wasnt the problem... the problem is just the APK must be singed, apparently eclipse use a debug sing and that's all, just sign fast and you are done :3

Answer (score 1):

I just got the same problem. The solution is to export your application as a `signed apk`. Otherwise your device would not let you install it.

If you use `Eclipse` and the `Android` plugin, once you start exporting it as a `signed apk`, it will ask you for a keystore. However, it will let you create one on the go if you want to so it's not much of a pain.
Once you finished the signed export, you can install it on your device.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve just had this problem .. It was quite problem to find it out. 
Copy your app icon picture to all folders drawable-hdpi, ldpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi. This helped me.
I didnt try which ones are mandatory and which not. Someone can try and upgrade my comment.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I had a space in the name of my Eclipse Workbench. I removed the space from my Eclipse Workbench (changed from "My Workbench" to "MyWorkbench"), then generated my APK and was able to install.  :-|